# How to reset user monthly usage in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cron

So I have a Meteor app, which allows users to do a particular task a certain number of times per month, depending on their subscription plan.

Their limit, current count and reset date are all stored in a MongoDB collection, but my question is how to reset the count on the specific date?

Would a simple cron-job do the trick?

TIA

Comment: Meteor has no task sheduler builtin so you will have to rely on an external one like node-cron.

Comment: There are a number of easy to use cron packages in the atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/?q=cron

Comment: @Jankapunkt Sure, I think I'll just use meteor-synced-cron - was just wondering if there'd be a better approach, than using a cron job...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Meteor Jobs package: https://github.com/vsivsi/meteor-job-collection

Basically you could schedule a regular job that scans your data to reset your customers.

Comment: I think I'll use meteor-synced-cron instead :) 

https://atmospherejs.com/littledata/synced-cron